# Powershell console different to script

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, tostring

Can anyone tell me why this command works fine in the Powershell console, returning a single thumbprint, but when run as a script it just returns all the certificate's thumbprints:

```
$crt = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting\ | Where-Object {$_.Subject.Contains($certcn)}).thumbprint
```

$certcn is a string containing a domain. eg "www.test.com"

Comment: `$certcn` is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. $certcn was derived from $args[0]. It turns out $args[0] is not a string, and even though PS would quite happily use it as a string in other commands, it would not do this with Where-Object.
Not sure what type $args[0] actually is, but doing $certcn = $args[0].tostring() fixed it.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the solution to your question.

Comment: Re finding out what type `$args[0]` actually is: use `$args[0].GetType().FullName`. To learn about a type's members, pass an instance to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member): `Get-Member -InputObject $args[0]`. It would be interesting to know what the actual type was, as it was seemingly converted to the _empty string_, which is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation for your symptom is that the **value of variable `$certcn`**:

- either: ***is* the *empty string* (`''`)** because `'someString'.Contains('')` returns `$true` for *any* input string.
- or: **is *implicitly converted* to the empty string**, though that wouldn't happen often in practice; here are some examples (see [GitHub issue #](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163) for the `[pscustomobject]` stringification bug mentioned below):

  ```sh
  # An empty array stringifies to ''
  'someString'.Contains(@()) # -> $true 

  # A single-element array containing $null stringifies to ''
  'someString'.Contains(@($null)) # -> $true 

  # Due to a longstanding bug, [pscustomobject] instances, when
  # stringified via .ToString(), convert to the empty string. 
  # This makes the command equivalent to `.Contains(@(''))`, which is again
  # the same as `.Contains('')`
  'someString'.Contains(@([pscustomobject] @{ foo=1 })) # -> $true
  ```

---

> `$args[0]` is not a string

The [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) is an array that contains all positional arguments that weren't bound to *declared parameters*, if any.

**`$args` can contain elements of *any data type*, and what that type is is solely determined *by the caller***.

However, **if you formally *declare* a parameter, you can *type* it**, which means that if the caller passes an argument of a different data type, an attempt is made to convert the argument to the parameter's type (which may fail, but at least the failure will be "loud", and the reason obvious).

---

**A robust solution for your script:**

```sh
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)] # Ensure that the caller passes a value.
  [string] $CertCN       # Type-constrain to a string.
  # , ... declare other parameters as needed
)

# $CertCN is now guaranteed to be a *string* that is *non-empty*.
$crt = 
  (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting | 
     Where-Object { $_.Subject.Contains($CertCN) }).thumbprint
```

Note:

- The [use of the `[Parameter()]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters#static-parameters) in the parameter declaration block (`param(...)`) makes your script an [*advanced* one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced), which means that `$args` isn't supported, requiring *all* arguments to bind to explicitly declared parameters; however, you can define a catch-all parameter with `[Parameter(ValueFromRemaningArguments)]`, if needed. (The other thing that makes a script or function an advanced one is use of the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute above the `param(...)` block as a whole.)
- `[Parameter(Mandatory)]`, in addition to ensuring that the caller passes a value for the parameter, implicitly also prevents passing the *empty* string (or `$null`) - though you could explicitly allow that with `[AllowEmptyString()]`
- Additionally, advanced scripts and functions automatically prevent passing *arrays* to `[string]`-typed parameters, which is desirable. (By contrast, *simple* functions and scripts simply *stringify* arrays, as would happen in expandable strings (string interpolation); e.g., `& { param([string] $foo) $foo } 1, 2` binds `'1 2'`, which is also what you'd get with `"$(1, 2)"`)

---

**Caveat**:

When **passing a value to a `[string]`-typed parameter**, PowerShell **accepts a scalar (non-collection) of *any type***, and any non-string type is ***automatically converted* to a string**, via `.ToString()`. This is **usually desirable and convenient, but can result in useless stringifications**; e.g.:

```sh
& { param([string] $str) $str } @{} # -> 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
```

Instances of [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) stringify to their *type name*, which is unhelpful, and this behavior is the default behavior for any type that doesn't explicitly implement a meaningful string representation by overriding the `.ToString()` method.

If that is a concern, you can **modify your script to ensure that the argument value being passed already *is* a string**, using a [`[ValidateScript()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) attribute.

```sh
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  # Ensure that the argument value is a [string] to begin with.
  # Note: The `ErrorMessage` property requires PowerShell (Core) 7+
  [ValidateScript({ $_ -is [string] }, ErrorMessage='Please pass a *string* argument.')]
  $CertCN  # Do not type-constrain, so that the original type can be inspected.
  # , ... declare other parameters as needed
)

# ...
```

As stated in the code comments, use of the `ErrorMessage` property in the requires *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, unfortunately. In *Windows PowerShell* a standard error message is invariably shown, which isn't user-friendly at all.